# How do I DLNA stream from GNOME to an Xbox One?

Tags: streaming, dlna, transcode

Say I have some video files in various formats that I want to stream to my Xbox One. Under Windows, I can choose the Xbox as a “playback device” from the file’s context-menu in Explorer.

As far as I understand it, this uses DLNA. However, I am unclear on how a server can initiate the playback on the device. Also, I’m not sure about transcoding and things.

Is there a program I can use as a on-demand server for DLNA purposes? (Click-on-a-file to stream, and then shut down afterwards.) Specifically, I only want to run the server on my laptop when I’m actually using it and not hurt my battery life when its not in use.

I guess I’m envisioning a VLC plug-in or something.
Does anyone have any insights or experience here?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you use [Plex Media Server](https://forums.plex.tv/index.php/topic/39443-so-you-want-your-dlna-device-to-work-with-pms/), or maybe even [Playstation Media Server](https://code.google.com/p/ps3mediaserver/).

Playstation Media Server is more lightweight and may fit your needs in a more simple manner, but Plex Media Server is more feature rich.

You can simply disable Plex Media Server at startup (`sudo update-rc.d -f <service name> disable`), and start/stop it using `service`.

Comment: This will not allow me to push content to the Xbox from my laptop. I would have to purchase a Plex client, purchase a Plex subscription, and have their server running all the time.

Comment: Playstation Media Server, even?

Comment: Yes, that would also be a DLNA server not a control point.